# Using an .SVG image background doesn't display?

Tags: css, svg, background-image

i have tried using an svg image as a background image in css on windows, but the image doesent appear and when i open the image in a separate tab it downloads the file instead of displaying it. Is there some other code needed to display svg files, or will they not display on a local site?
Any feedback welcome..

Comment: Which browser are you using? http://caniuse.com/svg-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not serving the image with the right [mime-type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type). How you set that depends on what web server you're using, look up setting mime types in the help for it. You want the svg image to be served as image/svg+xml